# App Suddenly Closes

Tags: iphone, ios4

Fellow developers.  My thanks to you all for your help and suggestions.

My app SafetyKnight has been approved for sale by Apple and I have submitted an inApp Purchase version for approval.

One last 'bug.' When first opening my app, it sometimes quits unexpectedly.  Not often.  But only rarely sometimes.

Does the MKMap or maybe not strong signal from communications provider cause an app to cut out at start-up?

Any thoughts or suggestions of code I might add to NOT have the app close/crash to enhance the user experience?

Comment: "make it not crash to *enhance the user experience* "? *sigh* iPhone people...

Comment: Apple approved an application that "sometimes quits unexpectedly"?

Comment: Do you not have some crash reports to indicate what it actually going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your app's memory usage during launch and initial view display.  The app might be running out of memory if a lot of other Apple processes (or background apps) are running (Mail fetch, music player, etc.).  Also make sure you are checking all your error and status return values from your networking code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have checked the memory usage and it is fine.  A little leakage from the MKMap as to be expected when the photos are in memory or processing.

Answer (score 1):

From the Organizer, you can access crash reports of any device connected to your computer.  Make your application run in debug mode on the device until it crashes and check in debugger where it happens.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check to see if I can duplicate the crash or at least monitor where the crash is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Did you handle the low memory notifications in the didReceiveMemoryWarning methods of the relevant UIViewControllers? What is the iOS you are building against?

Comment: I have MKMap in two view controllers. In one controller, I have the following code:

        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 [ locationManager stopUpdatingLocation ];
 [ locationManager release   ];

In the other view controller, I have only the [super didReceiveMemoryWarning].  Is this the point, if I get a memory warning, MKMap just quits even though I have not executed or called MKMap at the very beginning of my program.  In Instruments, I only see memory usage and only get a memory warning Level 1 when I use or am saving my photo taking.

What code is recommended for memory warnings?